# Get / Read Text File from URL - Javascript for After Effects

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I'm used to selecting, opening and reading a text file (CSV, JSON) from my local directory. I now have access to our data feeds online but don't know how to do the same thing with a URL instead of a local file.

For a local file I simply use something like this:

```
 var myFile = File.openDialog();
 myFile.open();
 myFile.read();
```

Is there a way to do this with a feed from a URL in javascript for AE?

Here is one of the feeds:  feeds.nfl.com/feeds-rs/schedules.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to save file, just one line do the trick =)

```
data = JSON.parse(system.callSystem('curl -s "https://path_to_json"'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in After Effects the easiest way is to do a system call.
The [Socket object](http://yearbookmachine.github.io/esdocs/#/Javascript/Socket) from ExtendScript is complicated. Look at [GetURLs.jsx](http://rorohiko.blogspot.de/2013/01/geturlsjsx.html) by Rorohiko.

You need to allow your script to access the network. See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665920/open-web-page-in-after-effects-with-extendscript)

```
# Mac Osx
var curlcmd = "curl feeds.nfl.com/feeds-rs/schedules.json > ~/Desktop/test/schedules.json";
var stdout = system.callSystem(curlcmd);
$.writeln(stdout);
var file = File("~/Desktop/test/schedules.json");
file.open();
var content = file.read();
file.close();
$.writeln(content);
```

Comment: Thank you fabiantheblind! I ended up using the GetURLs.jsx. I made some edits to it so that it worked with AE and it worked perfectly.